# Did a simple array and there seems to be a compile error

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomWithArray {
    public static void main(String[] args){
                Random r = new Random();

                int[] num = new int[5]; //same as "= {0,0,0,0,0}

                for (int i = 0; i <num.length; i++){
                    num[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
                }

                System.out.println(num[i]);

    }
}
```

Eclipse is telling me that on the print line,

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - i cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Line breakpoint:RandomWithArray [line: 14] - 
     main(String[])
```

What exactly did I do wrong?

Comment: `for`-loops are specifically designed to limit the scope of the loop control variable (in this case `i`). You can't access `i` outside the scope of the `for`-loop.

Comment: even if 'i' is defined outside there will be an arrayOutOfBounds exception when he accesses it outside

Answer (score 6):

because `i` is declared in for loop and you are using it out of scope.

The scope of variable `i` is limited to `for` block only.

If you want to iterate through the array, then you can use

```
for (int i = 0; i <num.length; i++){
      System.out.println(num[i]);
}
```

Or else, you can also use the enhanced for loop which is used especially for iterating over arrays and arraylists,

```
for(int i : num){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

This way you do not have to deal with the increment and index variable on your own.

Answer (score 0):

In support of @prasad kharkar's answer ,I would like to quote from the [section  14.4.2 of JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.4.2) :

> The **scope of a local variable** declaration in a block  is the rest of
>   the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own
>   initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the
>   local variable declaration statement.